# How to verify array length for postman test

Tags: javascript, arraylist, postman, newman, postman-testcase

I have json response showing 4 values (image showing 3) for this object `companies[0].salesReps`
How to verify postman test for total no of Sales employee and print their names on console.

```
x.companies[0].salesReps[0].name
x.companies[0].salesReps[1].name
x.companies[0].salesReps[2].name
```

[image: list]

Tried this saying **undefined**

```
emp = JSON.parse(responseBody(companies[0].salesReps));
    var listcnt = emp.length;
    console.log(listcnt)
```

Any thing missing :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about the structure of your response body, but this should do it.
Happy to adapt it, once you've posted your complete response body.

```
const resBody = pm.response.json();

const numberOfSalesEmployees = resBody.companies[0].salesReps.length;

console.log("Number of sales employees:" + numberOfSalesEmployees);

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSalesEmployees; i++){
    console.log("Name of sales rep " + i + ": " + resBody.companies[0].salesReps[i].name);
}

pm.test("Number of sales employees is 4", function () {
    pm.expect(numberOfSalesEmployees).to.eql(4);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, getting output for all four sales employee name as ` Name of sales rep 0: [object Object]`

Comment: As requested, please share your complete response body. Only then I can be sure about how to address the data and make the code work.

Comment: Got it work thanks Chris it was pointing to wrong object.  Updated this line and all working now :) `console.log("Name of sales rep " + i + ": " + (resBody.companies[0]).salesReps[i].name);`

Comment: Cool. Updated my answer. Thanks for accepting it in case it does what you asked for.

Comment: Accepted your answer  :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you'd be better off parsing responseBody first (before trying to access data in the response), so:

```
var parsedResponseBody = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var listCnt = parsedResponseBody.companies[0].salesReps.length;
```

Comment: This is only counting the number of sales reps. Question also asked to verify the number and print the sales rep's names.